# How does one find shops in Dwarf Fortress Adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

After spending more time than I'd care to admit learning and playing Dwarf Fortress Fortress mode over the last couple weeks I decided to give Adventure mode a shot. So far I'm getting the hang of it just fine, except I can't seem to find any shops to sell all the junk I'm hauling around. I'm in a Human Hamlet where the wiki would lead me to believe I should be able to find a shop, but so far no luck. Is there a trick to finding a shop? Maybe there's one here and I just don't realize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shops can be identified by the signs next to their door entryways, and can be <kbd>l</kbd>ooked at to determine the type of store.

Additionally, shops can only be found in the larger human towns (which show up in yellow, as opposed to white on the adventurer map).